# anti-spoofing measures for SAQ C business with iPads/NCR silver

Tags: pci-dss, spoofing

So I'm just wondering what types of anti-spoofing measures a SAQ-C business would need:

https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/PCI-DSS-v3_2_1-SAQ-D_Merchant.pdf

There's a lot of built in security measures with iPads using NCR silver, the information typically just goes through apple servers in the end. Does this business setup require any *additional* anti-spoofing measures to be sufficiently secure?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it also needs to be in its own subnet that only contains devices that process payment information.

Comment: what about devices masquerading as the subnet?